# Cannot find Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch Type in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to create a report in SSRS (Visual Studio 2012) for Dynamics 2011 using fetchXML. I have downloaded and installed the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Report Authoring Extension (with SQL Server Data Tools support) but I cannot find the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch Type when I try to create a report, please, does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to create the report in some already existed project, I had the same issue with VS2010 in that case.

To make Fetch XML data source be visible you must create **new** project in Visual Studio. If all installations were successful, you must be able to create project with Business Intelligence/Report Server Project template, than create new report and in Report Data window (if it not appears automatically - just click on any place on report, go to View menu and find Report Data window) right click on Datasets, than pick "Use a dataset embeded in my report", click "New..." button near Data source drop down and there you should see Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch connection type.

Have no possibility to test this with VS2012, hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the latest version of SQL is SQL 2012 and BIDS for it is done using VS2010. So answer is quite simple - you would not be able to build a report using VS2012, you will have to use VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [Report Authoring Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27823). Install these and you'll have the FetchXML in the list.

If you've upgraded to a later CRM version since this post, just search on that version of extension installer instead (2013/2015/2016).