# Unable to get "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch" in Data Source options for SSRS reports project for CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, ssrs-2012, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a problem very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098962/cannot-find-microsoft-dynamics-crm-fetch-type-in-ssrs)

I have installed "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension" for Dynamics CRM 2015. Installed BIDS for Sql Server 2012 and working with VS 2013 Community Edition. Windows Live sign-in assistant is also installed.

I created a new project with Business Intelligence/Report Server Project and went on to Add New Data Source but see the following list with no option for **"Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch"**
[image]

Apparently, there seems to be no errors. Can anyone give me some ideas or suggestions on what to do to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Report Authoring Extension (with SQL Server Data Tools support) doesn't support VS 2013. Here is part of System Requirements:

> The following components are required:
>
> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
>
> -- OR --
> Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Data Tools
>     To install SQL Server Data Tools, on the PC running Visual Studio 2010 go to the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express download page,
> ```
>
> download the following files appropriate to your CPU architecture and
>   language:
>               ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
>               ENU\x86\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe
>           Select the "SSDT" or "SQL Server Data Tools" installation.

Check system requirements here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45013

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will install 2012 and let you know if that works.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Although not supporting VS2013 doesn't make much sense. Thanks for the help @Andrii

Comment: does it support VS2015?  before I head down the same rabbit hole :)

Comment: As far as I know at the moment the only supported version is VS 2012.